# Unable to Show Image In ImageView From Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have an app which allows the users to upload the images to a Firebase bucket,then I get the download URL of the image file and add it to a firebase database.The URL is in the form :-  `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bucket_name.appspot.com/o/filename?alt=media&token=token`

Then I try to load the images into an RecyclerView using Glide but I am unable to do so and It fails to display the image.

How can I get an absolute Image URL which ends in .png or .jpeg etc which can be easily used to load the image.As far as I know the problem is with the url

Comment: If you've already tried something that didn't work, edit your question to include the minimum code to reproduce your problem. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For a minimal example that uses Glide and *does* work, see the code of the [Zero to App talk at I/O](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAsvwy1-oxE): https://gist.github.com/puf/f49a1b07e92952b44f2dc36d9af04e3c

Comment: Actually The Main Problem is not with glide but with the firebase download link. A Link Ending in .png can be loaded into that imageview but whenever I but a firebase download link the image doesn't load

Comment: The same issue anyone got this solution?

Answer (score 2):

To get Images form Camera

```
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(i, 3);
```

To get the filepath of an Image

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_FILE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

      String  path=String.valueOf(data.getData());
      file = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
```

Create the file metadata

```
  metadata = new StorageMetadata.Builder()
    .setContentType("image/jpeg")
    .build();
```

Upload file and metadata to the path 'images/avator.jpg'

```
  uploadTask = storageRef.child("images/"+file.getLastPathSegment()).putFile(file, metadata);
```

Listen for state changes, errors, and completion of the upload.

```
  uploadTask.addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
@Override
public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
    double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
    System.out.println("Upload is " + progress + "% done");
}
}).addOnPausedListener(new OnPausedListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
@Override
public void onPaused(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
    System.out.println("Upload is paused");
}
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
 @Override
public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
    // Handle unsuccessful uploads
}
}).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
    // Handle successful uploads on complete
    Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getDownloadUrl();

}
```

});

To load the Image using Glide Library

```
  Glide.with(getActivity())
.load(new File(downloadUrl)) // Uri of the picture
.into(Imageview);
```

Answer (score 1):

With Picasso you can load a simple image using:

```
Picasso.with(Activity.this).load("your url image").into(imageView);
```

Need add in Glade:

```
 compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Comment: I tried with Picasso and used the latest lib also as per this link https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/1574 but no success

Comment: @AnantShah which problems happens?

Comment: @ Diego Venâncio not able to load firebase storage image's downloadable url to Picasso library shows nothing if I pass that url. If I use other(Non-firebase storage image url) url then it works.
I updated Picasso lib also.