# Setting imageView from Firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, android-imageview, firebase-storage

How can I set an image to an imageView directly from Firebase, given I already have the url to the user's uploaded image?

Comment: You can use Any networking library . Volley or Retrofit or Picasso

Comment: Show code how do you display image?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to Show Image In ImageView From Firebase Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38170940/608639), [How to display or get an image from Firebase storage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41737271/608639), [Unable to show images from Firebase Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37525131/608639), etc. More generally, [firebase display imageview storage site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase+display+imageview+storage+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 0):

> if you have image URL available at client side. Implement
>   [GLIDE](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) and pass the URL and ImageView to Glide. It will take care of showing the image to client.

```java
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView_ID);

RequestOptions requestOption = new RequestOptions()
        .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_error_1)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .priority(Priority.HIGH)
                .dontAnimate()
                .dontTransform()

new Glide
    .with(mcontext)
        .load("https://placeholder.com/img/products/imageurl.png")
        .apply(requestOption)
        .thumbnail(0.1f)
        .into(imageView)
```

> add dependency 
>   implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
>       annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'

Answer (score 0):

You can use image loading library like Glide or Picasso,

1st add the dependency in build.gradle (Moduke:App) under dependencies,

```
dependencies {
....
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
}
```

Then at the activity where your image view is load the image from url:

```
Glide.with(this).load(IMAGE_URL).into(imageView);
```

IMAGE_URL is the firebase storage url for the image, and imageView is where you displaying the image.

Follow https://bumptech.github.io/glide/ for more info

Answer (score -1):

```
          private CircleImageView uDisplayImage;
  currentFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

            String uId = currentFirebaseUser.getUid();
            myRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference("user").child(uId);
      myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {



                    image = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();


                    if (!image.equals("default")) {

                        Picasso.get().load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.idofcircularview).into(uDisplayImage);
                    }



                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Toast.makeText(SattingsActivity.this, "Sorry Data is not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```